# How to prevent calling anchor tag action on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am calling a action through s:url and the action is called form a anchor link click like this

```
<div  class ="QuickLink"><ul><li>
<s:url namespace="/np" action="actionName1" var="URL_ID_ONE" />
<a id="theLink1"  href="%{URL_ID_ONE}" targets="RIGHT_PANEL">Click One</a></li><li>
<s:url namespace="/np" action="actionName2" var="URL_ID_TWO" />
<a id="theLink2"  href="%{URL_ID_TWO}" targets="RIGHT_PANEL">Click Two</a></li></ul></div>
```

What I need is on click of anchor link. i will check a condition if it returns false, then I need to stop calling the action called through href

tried using `event.preventDefault()`, `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` for anchor click event
Not working any of the event stop functions defined in jquery doc.

Comment: can you show us the click binding code?

Comment: onClick="return false;"

Comment: @john your javascript code will help also

Comment: $('#theLink').live('click', function(e){
var getStat= $('#MARK_REVIEWED_BUTTON');
if (getStat.attr('disabled') !='disabled'){  $('#MARK_REVIEWED_BUTTON').pulsate({glow:false,color:'#D00'});
e.preventDefault();
} 
});

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#theLink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

you need to reference the event originating from the [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/),

**Update**

You are only conditionally cancelling the event (it is inside the if statement), put the cancel up top of function

```
$(document).on('click','#theLink',function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
     var getStat= $('#MARK_REVIEWED_BUTTON'); 
    if (getStat.attr('disabled') !='disabled'){ 
    $('#MARK_REVIEWED_BUTTON').pulsate({glow:false,color:'#D00'}); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: hi, as i said event functions is not working instead of preventing its calling the added action...javascript code added in my question please have alook

Comment: I would also change this to use the `on` event handler.  `live` works but is deprecated and just calls `on` behind the scenes.  `$('#thLink').on('click', function(e)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("selector").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
   });
    </script>
```

try using event inside the function e.g. function(event)

Answer (score 0):

The callback should return false to prevent the href action:

```
$('#someid').bind('click',function(){alert('hello'); return false;})
```

It's asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222466/how-to-stop-href-going-anywhere